# zsh completion doesn't work when prepending to word

Tags: zsh

I have two versions of a certain application, the one in my PATH and one at `~/install/app`. So normally I do

`app file`

But sometimes I want to do, right after that:

`~/install/app file`

With bash I would

`app file`<kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> to position the cursor in the begining of the line (I use vim keybindings)

Then, with the cursor in the beginning of the line, start typing `~/install` and complete with <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

`~/ins`<kbd>TAB</kbd>`app file`

`~/install/app file`

However, with zsh the completion does not work, because there is no space between `~/ins` and `app`, so it doesn't know what to do. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bindkey -M viins '^I' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

…and <kbd>TAB</kbd> should work the way you like it in vi insert mode.